# Why do my kernel dies and restart while training my neural network with PyTorch?

Tags: python, jupyter, pytorch

I'm a beginner with python and PyTorch and I've got to implement a neural network for image recognition.

Everything works fine except that my kernel dies and restart automatically at the 78th iteration. At each iteration, we are training the network on a batch of 64 images (the full set has 5000 images).

I am using a Macbook Pro (10.14), and I installed Pytorch using pip. This is the very first time I encounter this issue.

I dig a bit on the internet and it might be a memory issue?

Thanks for reading!

```
 epochs = 10
 steps = 0
 print_every = 20
 running_loss = 0 
 for e in range(epochs):
 start = time.time()

 for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(iter(valloader)):
    steps += 1

    images.resize_(64, 3072)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = net.forward(images)
    loss = loss_func(output, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    running_loss += loss.item()
```

Comment: If you use GPUs try to check `nvidia-smi` command for usage of memory. Does it throw some error?

Comment: Could be various reasons. If it's a memory issue - probably CPU Memory, GPU memory should result in an error message. If your CPU memory is exceeded your python process might just get killed by your OS. But it could be also a bug, in some OS / Pytorch version combinations I got my kernel killed for certain operations. But before considering this be sure to check your CPU memory first! If this doesn't work I would try some other pytorch version.

Comment: Apparently, all of my CPU is used by python during iterations, it goes up to 141% and the kernel crashes. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix it?          I installed python with anaconda on an other computer and I've got the same issue. Did I do something wrong in my code?

Comment: @PaulMermod Did you managed to resolve it?

Comment: This often happens if you consume too much memory and the OS kills the python process. Keep an eye on your process memory.

Answer (score 0):

My MacBook rebooted when I've been starting training a neural network. There was a kernel panic message in a report.

I don't know the exact root cause of the kernel panic. Maybe the CPU was overheated.

But I had a chance to continue my work when I decreased batch sizes from 8 to 1.